# Auto Scroll para View Específica

Tags: android

Eu tenho um ScrollView com vários elementos dentro, LinearLayout, Imagens, Textviews etc.

No cabeçalho, acima do scrollview tenho alguns botões, no OnClickListener de um deles quero fazer um auto scroll para que a aplicação mostre na tela aquele elemento que desejo, no caso, o inicio de um LinearLayout.

Dá para resolver com linearlayout.requestFocus(), mas não tem scroll, há alguma outra forma que a aplicação mostre o scrool deslizando até a view que desejo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
vertical_scroll.scrollTo(0, exibirEste.getTop());
```

Se o Elemento não estiver dentro do vertical_scroll, deve se levar em consideração a posição do pai:

```
int position = (exibirEste.getTop() + layoutPai.getTop());
vertical_scroll.scrollTo(0, position);
```

**EDIT:**

Para suavizar a animação use:

```
int position = (exibirEste.getTop() + layoutPai.getTop());
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(vertical_scroll, "scrollY",  position).setDuration(1000).start();
```

Sendo, `setDuration(1000)` o tempo que a animação deve durar!

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou.
Se não for abusar, a velocidade de rolagem até o ponto, posso controlar?

Comment: Editei a resposta! =)

Comment: Perfeito! funcionou certinho. muito obrigado.